# How can I generate PI number to the precision of my choice?

Tags: java, encryption, pi

I am making a basic encryption program that is based on PI number. (IN JAVA)

However, when I make use the function Math.PI, I only get 3.141592653589793 and nothing more.

So I was wondering if there is a method in which I can up to 300~500th digit of Pi.

Thank you

Comment: You'll need to compute this yourself, and use something like BigDecimal to store it. See https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~alopez-o/math-faq/node38.html for a few possible algorithms you could use.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how (and why) you use Pi for encryption?

Comment: Just putting it out there, but whatever you are doing with it, you almost certainly shouldn't. use an existing library, like `javax.crypto` for real encryption.

Comment: Also, Pi is not a good source of entropy. If you are just experimenting with crypto, you should still use a real CSPRNG to generate the digits. (Basically, instead of using `pi.getNextDigit()`, use `csprngWithPrearrangedSeed.getNextDigit()`.)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of them, actually. Here's a place to get you started with algorithms.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Computer_era_and_iterative_algorithms

Calculate it by yourself is costly though. You can download quite precise values of it ready-to-use, for example here: http://pi.karmona.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [spigot algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Spigot_algorithms) to generate your digits, if you think that you are going to need so many of them that storing them all would be a problem.

A more advanced type of algorithm is a Digit Extraction Algorithm; with one of those, you can not only compute the sequence, but compute any arbitrary digit from anywhere in the sequence.

If there is no real, binding requirement in your system that you use Pi for the encryption, then **you should not use Pi at all**. You should use a real CSPRNG to generate your digit stream, instead, because Pi is far to easy to predict for it to make a good cryptosystem. (If the reason you are using Pi is so you can get the same stream on each end, rest assured that you can get the same sequence at each end from a CSPRNG by just seeding them with the same value.)